# What is the period of $(2007)^{\sin x}$?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

What is the period of $(2007)^{\sin x}$? Please explain how to proceed and what's the technique to generally solve these kind of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(x+2\pi) = 2007^{\sin(x+2\pi)} = 2007^{\sin(x)} = f(x)$

Comment: This proves $2\pi$ is *a* period.  It does not show that it is the minimal period.

Comment: $2007^{sin(x+t)}=2007^{sin(x)}\to sin(x+t)=sin(x)\to x+t=2k\pi+x\to x=2k\pi$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki I believe you mean that $t=2k\pi$ and not $x$. Also, you should ad this to the body of your answer. It seems kind of wierd to just leave this a comment.

Comment: yes it was typo

Answer (score 5):

Period of $(2007)^{\sin x}$ = period of $\sin x$ = $2\pi$ since the periodicity of the function depends on $\sin x$ only, irrespective that is in the exponent.

$$\psi(x+2\pi)=(2007)^{\sin (x+2\pi)}=(2007)^{\sin x}=\psi(x)$$

Comment: Awesome job done! So this explains how the period of $(2008)^{cosx}$ comes out to be $pi$?

Comment: @Ujjwal, The period of $(2008)^{\cos(x)}$ is not $\pi$ as you claim. Note that $(2008)^{\cos(0)} = 2008^1 = 2008$ whereas $2008^{\cos(\pi)} = 2008^{-1} = \frac{1}{2008}$.

Comment: @Ujjwal It is $2\pi$ and not $\pi$.

Comment: This proves $2\pi$ is *a* period. It does not show that it is the minimal period.